# How to save the disability of a button for Xcode

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

what i am to do with the button is once it is pressed it will disable for the rest of the day. now my code does disable it once it is pressed but if the user leaves the application and comes back to it, the button will be enabled again. is there a way to use NSUserDefaults?

```
let save = UserDefaults.standard
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
```

this is in the viewDidLoad:

```
    let seven_today = calendar.date(
        bySettingHour: 7,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        of: now)!

    let two_thirty_today = calendar.date(
        bySettingHour: 14,
        minute: 30,
        second: 0,
        of: now)!

    if now >= seven_today && now <= two_thirty_today

    {
        getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = true
    }

    else

    {
        getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false
    }
```

this is the function of pressing the button:

```
 Total_Points += 12
 pointsLabel.text = "Total Points: \(Total_Points)"
 getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  if now >= seven_today && now <= two_thirty_today

  {

     let savedDayNum = defaults.integer(forKey: "dayClickNum")


     let date = Date()

     let calendar = Calendar.current

     let nowDayNum = calendar.component(.day, from: date)


    if(savedDayNum == nowDayNum)
    {
         getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false
    }
    else
    {
         getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = true
    }
  }

  else

 {
      getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false
 }
```

// in function click do this

```
 Total_Points += 12

 pointsLabel.text = "Total Points: \(Total_Points)"  

 getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false


 let date = Date()

 let calendar = Calendar.current

 let dayOfClickDate = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

 defaults.set(dayOfClickDate, forKey: "dayClickNum")
```

Also for a perfect solution you may take care of month , as app may not be launched again by user for a month that may disable the button if the stored num day is coincidence d with open day of another month

Comment: The first time the app is run, this code will cause the button to be disabled since `defaults.boolForKey("buttonStatus")` will return `false` initially. Either register a proper default to get `true` initially or adjust the logic as needed.

Comment: I  know , I meant to set a true value initially in first launch , but for simplicity i updated it with other option

Comment: @Sh_Khan well i want the user to be able to click the button in the interval, having it to check if its within 24hrs will not allow the user to press the button at 10am if they pressed it at 10:30am the day before

Comment: you want 24 hrs to span days or want to disable rest of day if it's clicked say at 11:30 PM ???

Comment: so i want the button to be enabled from 7am -230pm and then disabled whether they clicked it or not and then when they do press the button and it is between that interval, the button will be disabled and reenabled the next day at 7am

the problem with my app is that it enables again even if they pressed the button that day

Comment: i see but what is `nowDayNum` ? i have Date() implemented with now but how could i get the num?

Comment: I would love to mark it but it is not fully correct. I am getting an error stating that it cannot resolve `nowDayNum`

Comment: you only defined `savedDayNum`

Comment: Changed line to this.         let savedDayNum = defaults.integer(forKey: "dayClickNum")

Comment: so from what you're saying right now, it would be `if(savedDayNum==savedDayNum)`????? please edit your answer ...error-free so I can mark it as correct I am just a little confused